# UICollectionViewCell: expand text with "See More" button - AutoSizing

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell, autosize

I'm using UICollectionView AutoSizing cells with multiple `UILabel`s placed into the `UIStackView`.

I need to expand the label **and the cell** when the user taps on the *"See more"* button.

So far, I'm able to update the label, **but the update doesn't trigger the `UICollectionView` to update the cell's size.**

**Before the update:**

[image]

**After the update:**

[image]

Code I tried to update the cell:

```
  var collapsed = true {
    didSet {
      subtitle.numberOfLines = collapsed ? 2 : 0
      subtitle.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
      subtitle.setNeedsLayout()
      subtitle.setNeedsDisplay()
      subtitle.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
  }
```

*layoutSubviews()* gets called, but *preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* not.

I need to trigger the call to the *preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* method.

**Update:**

This "hack" works great:

```
  func invalidate() {
    guard let collection = superview as? UICollectionView else {return}
    collection.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
  }
```

**How can I mark only specific cell to be resized?**

**[Video of the effect I'm trying to achieve](https://streamable.com/wgjm8)**

Comment: Did you try to reload selected cell?

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me best (when using AutoSizing cells):

`collection.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)`